# Script to get the type (hold, breakdown, extreme) of active key

Tags: python, keyframes

I need a python script to check if the current keyframe in the timeline is of the 'Extreme' type. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a direct way to determine the keyframe by frame number. However you can iterate through the keyframes of a given object and check if the x-coordinate of the keyframe matches the current frame. Once you have retrieved the keyframe you can access the [type](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Keyframe.html#bpy.types.Keyframe.type).

> **type**
>
> Type of keyframe (for visual purposes only)
>
> - `KEYFRAME` Keyframe, Normal keyframe - e.g. for key poses.
> - `BREAKDOWN` Breakdown, A breakdown pose - e.g. for transitions between key poses.
> - `MOVING_HOLD` Moving Hold, A keyframe that is part of a moving hold.
> - `EXTREME` Extreme, An ‘extreme’ pose, or some other purpose as needed.
> - `JITTER` Jitter, A filler or baked keyframe for keying on ones, or some
>     other purpose as needed.

---

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
fcurves = obj.animation_data.action.fcurves
current_frame = bpy.context.scene.frame_current + bpy.context.scene.frame_subframe

for fcurve in fcurves:
    for keyframe in fcurve.keyframe_points:
        if keyframe.co[0] == current_frame:
            print(f"{keyframe.co}: {keyframe.type}")
```